# How to insert a square to an image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to insert a rectangle to an image in Matlab. I used the code below, it did not gave me an error but it did not insert anything as well. What am I doing wrong?

```
insertShape(my_picture, 'rectangle', [ex, ey, 35, 35], 'LineWidth', 5); 
imwrite(my_picture, 'lena_after_convolution_nose.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A square is actually added but you're not writing the new image to the disk. You're writing the old one instead.

```
new_pic = insertShape(my_picture, 'rectangle', [ex, ey, 35, 35], 'LineWidth', 5); 
imwrite(new_pic , 'lena_after_convolution_nose.jpg');
```